# Material is flickering in Unity

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I'm trying to make a grid like, light up floor using Unity's Shader Graph. However, I am having an issue where the lines are flicking after a really short distance when the camera is moving.

[image: Issue]

The shader graph is below.

[image: Shader graph]

How can this issue be prevented and what is causing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Foxwarrior says, this issue is due to [spatial aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing). At a certain distance away, the stripes on your plane pack together closer than you have pixels/samples to display them: so whether the sample point lands in a bright or a dark patch depends sensitively on the position of the camera. A tiny offset can make a distant pixel jump suddenly from light to dark or dark to light, creating a noticeable flicker as your camera moves.

You can fix this by changing your shader graph to analytically integrate the brightness of your grid over the full square the pixel covers - so rather than sampling just the point at the center of the pixel, you get an averaged-out value that changes more gradually under small camera movements, or blurs the grid toward an average colour when it becomes too fine to sample accurately.

> [image: Filtered / Unfiltered Grid]
>
> On the right, a grid rendered with your current technique, showing severe aliasing in the distance, dissolving into static as pixels hit lines or holes almost at random.
>
> On the left, a box-filtered grid, where the white lines fade into the distance as they get finer (instead of maintaining the same full brightness even when they account for only a fraction of a pixel).

[Inigo Quilez has shared a number of analytical integration formulas here](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/filterableprocedurals/filterableprocedurals.htm). We can use the "Box Filtered Grid" example:

```
float filteredSquares( in vec2 p, in vec2 dpdx, in vec2 dpdy )
{
    const float N = 3.0;
    vec2 w = max(abs(dpdx), abs(dpdy));
    vec2 a = p + 0.5*w;                        
    vec2 b = p - 0.5*w;           
    vec2 i = (floor(a)+min(fract(a)*N,1.0)-
              floor(b)-min(fract(b)*N,1.0))/(N*w);
    return 1.0-i.x*i.y;
}
```

And convert it to a shader graph like so:

[image: The code above, expressed as a Unity Shader Graph]

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks a lot better with this in

Answer (score 4):

When the renderer draws something to the screen, it takes one or a few samples of each pixel and puts the average color there. Light gray to dark gray could be that the pixel has been sampled at 3 white, 1 black in one frame, and 1 white, 3 black in the next. Moiré patterns are the related physical phenomenon.

You can increase the number of samples with Anti-Aliasing settings (it's resource-intensive though) or try messing around with mip-mapping settings or Shader Graph depth effects to have it blur the far away parts so the lines end up being a more consistent gray instead of flickering so much.

A completely different approach to drawing the grid using vector art instead of 3D rendering may also work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It provided some good research points if I get time to revisit this in the future